# Factorizations as a product of primes minus one

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Let $x$ be a positive rational number. I am interested in factorizing $x$ as a product of primes minus one. In fact, I would also like make sure the primes in the decomposition are distinct, and I want to impose congruence conditions on the primes (the application is too far afield to describe). Let me break down my main question (Q3) into some warm-ups. There are also some special cases following Q3.

**Q1.** Let $x$ be a positive rational number. Are there collections

$$
P = \{p_1, \dots, p_m\}
$$
$$
Q = \{q_1, \dots, q_n\}
$$

of $n+m$ odd prime numbers with $P \cap Q = \emptyset$ such that

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i = 1}^m (p_i - 1) = x \prod_{j = 1}^n (q_j - 1)? \tag{1}
\end{equation}

We can call each such instance of (1) a *factorization of $x$ into a product of primes minus one*. If the answer is yes, can $x$ have infinitely many such factorizations?

**Q2.** Does Q1 still have a yes answer if we require the sets to be distinct primes, i.e., that $P \cup Q$ is $m+n$ distinct prime numbers? In other words, can we take each prime in the factorization to appear with multiplicity one? (Unlike the case of factorization into a product of primes, this is actually quite natural.)

My main question:

**Q3.** Does Q2 still have a yes answer if we put "legal" congruence constraints on the sets $P$ and $Q$? By "legal", I mean that the congruence conditions don't trivially make the equation impossible (e.g., a condition mod $N$ that makes the equation unsolvable modulo N or some divisor/multiple of $N$).

*Example.* Take $x = 4$ with the condition that the primes in $P$ are $3$ or $5$ mod $8$ and the primes in $Q$ are $1$ or $7$ mod $8$. Then $(5-1) = 4$, but also

$$
(11-1)(13-1) = 4(31-1)
$$

so $P = \{11, 13\}$, $Q = \{31\}$ works.

Moreover, suppose there is an integer $k$ so that $13+16k$ and $31+40k$ are simultaneously prime. Then $P = \{11, 13+16k\}$, $Q = \{31+40k\}$ also works. It follows from [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture) that infinitely many such $k$ exist, but I believe this particular case is open. There are $27768$ such $k$ between zero and a million, $211502$ up to ten million, and $1665924$ up to a hundred million. It's pretty reasonable to guess this isn't a counterexample to Dickson's conjecture...

One could also perhaps motivate this question by recent work of [Tao--Ziegler](https://doi.org/10.1017/fmp.2017.3) on polynomial patterns in the primes (and preceding results found in its references).

Some experimentation suggests a special case:

**Q4.** Can we always take $P$ and $Q$ to be of bounded cardinality to produce infinitely many distinct factorizations of $x$?

For example, all positive integers $x$ between $1$ and $100$ are of the form

$$
(p-1)(q-1)=x(r-1)
$$

for $p,q,r$ distinct.

**Q5.** If the answers to any of Q1-Q4 end up being no, can we characterize the positive rational numbers (or integers) $x$ for which the answer is yes?

Honestly, I would even be happy if $x=4$ admits infinitely many factorizations subject to the congruence conditions given in the example.

Comment: I don't know if for any integers r and s there is an integer k such that both rk +1 and sk + 1 are prime. Given the Cebotarev density theorem I expect the answer to be yes with infinitely many positive integers k.  If we focused on this statement alone , a yes answer would seem to take care of all your questions.  Gerhard "Am I Right About This?" Paseman, 2019.06.23.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman That statement is certainly conjectured, but probably has about the same difficulty as the twin primes conjecture.

Comment: There is an extensive literature on "shifted primes". If you search on that phrase, you may find something useful.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yes, that would certainly give it. As Will Sawin says, this is a (likely) hard conjecture. The pair of arithmetic progressions in my example is of a similar nature.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks! I did find an [interesting paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1332910) by Elliott about the subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^*$ generated by quotients of the form $(p+1)/(q+1)$ for $p,q$ prime, which has some nice follow-up work, but nothing quite what I'm after.